# Make push-notification of a new post on an android app

Tags: php, android, wordpress, push-notification, xml-parsing

I want to make an app for a wordpress blog but need a very specific feature to be there i.e whenever a new post is made a pushnotification should be made in the user's mobile. how to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-push-notification/#description) Plugin in Your Wordpress and use GCM/FCM API Key for sending the push notification in Android App